# difference between real mode and protected mode on x64 architecture

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, bootloader

What is the difference between real mode and protected mode on the x64 architecture? I'm trying to make a custom boot-loader for the Linux kernel. How can I enable protected mode in assembly?

Comment: Read the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual, Volume 3: System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html); or the [AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 2: System Programming](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/).

Answer (score 2):

see osdev [real mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode), [protected mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode).

A CPU that is initialized by the BIOS starts in Real Mode. Enabling Protected Mode allows use of all 4GB memory that cannot be accessed by real mode. However, it will prevent you from using most of the BIOS interrupts, since these work in Real Mode (unless you have also written a V86 monitor).

Before switching to Protected Mode, you have to disable interrupts, possibly enable the A20 Line, and load the Global Descriptor Table with segment descriptors suitable for code, data, and stack.

Whether the CPU is in Real Mode or in Protected Mode is defined by the lowest bit of the CR0 or MSW register.

This example loads a descriptor table into the processor's GDTR register, and then sets the lowest bit of CR0:

```
cli          ; disable interrupts
lgdt [gdtr]  ; load GDT register with start address of Global Descriptor Table
mov eax, cr0 
or al, 1     ; set PE (Protection Enable) bit in CR0 (Control Register 0)
mov cr0, eax

; Perform far jump to selector 08h (offset into GDT, pointing at a 32bit PM code segment descriptor) 
; to load CS with proper PM32 descriptor)

JMP 08h:PModeMain

; [...]

PModeMain:
; load DS, ES, FS, GS, SS, ESP.
```

This takes you to Protected Mode.
After this you can jump to your kernel code in C or Assembly.